# C# listas creadas a partir de clases y utilizando métodos

Tags: c#

buenas tengo un ejercicio en C# el cual me pide crear una lista, recorrerla y mostrarla.
debo crear una clase lista y otra clase nodo, e invocar métodos que realicen lo pedido.

mi código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class lista
    {
        nodo primero;
        nodo ultimo;
        
        public lista()
        {
            primero = null;
            ultimo = null;
        }
        public void InsertarNodo()
        {
            nodo nuevo = new nodo();
            Console.WriteLine("Insertar nombre y apellido");
            nuevo.nombre_apellido = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Insertar DNI");
            nuevo.dni = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Insertar edad");
            nuevo.edad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (primero == null)
            {
                primero = nuevo;
                primero.siguiente = null;
                ultimo = nuevo;
            } 
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre y apellido: {0} \n DNI: {1} \n Edad: {2}", nuevo.nombre_apellido, nuevo.dni, nuevo.edad);
            
        }
        public void MostrarLista()
        {
            nodo actual = new nodo();
            actual = primero;


            if (actual != null)
            {
                while (actual != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(actual.nombre_apellido);
                    Console.WriteLine(actual.dni);
                    Console.WriteLine(actual.edad);
                    actual = actual.siguiente;
                }
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Lista vacía");
        } public void RecorrerLista()
        {

        }
        
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class nodo
    {
        public string nombre_apellido;
        public int dni;
        public int edad;
        public nodo siguiente;
    }
}
```

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            lista l = new lista();
            l.InsertarNodo();
            l.InsertarNodo();
            l.InsertarNodo();
            l.MostrarLista();
        }
    }
}
```

El programa funciona, el problema está en que cuando muestro la lista solo imprime el primer nodo y el último, y los nodos del medio no son visto. Supongo que habrá algún error en el método o falta agregar algo, que es con lo que no puedo dar.

Y si alguien quiere ayudarme un poco más, hoy tengo examen y el ejercicio se trata de crear una lista, recorrerla y además mezclar la lista con un arreglo o matriz. Podrían ayudarme con algún código de ejemplo?

Espero que se entienda, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El nodo ultimo no tiene sentido, así que lo eliminé. En una lista enlaza te quedas con el primero y recorres hacia el final

(poner el último es para listas circulares)

Tu problema no está en mostrarlos, está cuando los ingresas

```
if (primero == null)
{
    primero = nuevo;
    primero.siguiente = null;
    ultimo = nuevo;
}
```

Si `primero` es distinto de nulo, no ingresas nada.
Para ingresar un nuevo nodo debes posicionarte en el último nodo

De esta manera:

```
if (primero == null)
{
    primero = nuevo;
}
else
{
    nodo actual = primero;
    while (actual.siguiente != null)
    {
        actual = actual.siguiente;
    }
    actual.siguiente = nuevo;
}
```

Código completo:

```
    internal class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            lista l = new lista();
            l.InsertarNodo();
            l.InsertarNodo();
            l.InsertarNodo();
            Console.WriteLine("=========");
            l.MostrarLista();
        }
    }


}
class lista
{
    nodo primero = null;

    public void InsertarNodo()
    {
        nodo nuevo = new nodo();
        Console.WriteLine("===============================");
        Console.WriteLine("Insertar nombre y apellido");
        nuevo.nombre_apellido = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Insertar DNI");
        nuevo.dni = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Insertar edad");
        nuevo.edad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (primero == null)
        {
            primero = nuevo;
        }
        else
        {
            nodo actual = primero;
            while (actual.siguiente != null)
            {
                actual = actual.siguiente;
            }
            actual.siguiente = nuevo;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre y apellido: {0} \n DNI: {1} \n Edad: {2}", nuevo.nombre_apellido, nuevo.dni, nuevo.edad);

    }
    public void MostrarLista()
    {
        nodo actual = primero;

        if (actual != null)
        {
            while (actual != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("===============================");
                Console.WriteLine(actual.nombre_apellido);
                Console.WriteLine(actual.dni);
                Console.WriteLine(actual.edad);
                Console.WriteLine("===============================");
                actual = actual.siguiente;
            }
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Lista vacía");
    }
    public void RecorrerLista()
    {

    }

}
class nodo
{
    public string nombre_apellido;
    public int dni;
    public int edad;
    public nodo siguiente;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (actual != null)
        {
            while (actual != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(actual.nombre_apellido);
                Console.WriteLine(actual.dni);
                Console.WriteLine(actual.edad);
                actual = actual.siguiente;
            }
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Lista vacía");
```

prueba con sacar el IF y el ELSE (deja el while) a ver si te imprime todo.